# Why does static NSString leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I have the following code to retrieve file paths on my iOS Apps:

```
static const NSString * fullPathFromRelativePath(NSString *relPath)
{
    // do not convert a path starting with '/'
    if(([relPath length] > 0) && ([relPath characterAtIndex:0] == '/'))
        return relPath;

    NSMutableArray *imagePathComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[relPath pathComponents]];

    NSString *file = [imagePathComponents lastObject];    
    [imagePathComponents removeLastObject];

    NSString *imageDirectory = [NSString pathWithComponents:imagePathComponents];

    NSString *fullpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file
                                                         ofType:NULL
                                                    inDirectory:imageDirectory];
    if (!fullpath)
        fullpath = relPath;

    return fullpath;    
}

static const char * fullCPathFromRelativePath(const char *cPath)
{
    NSString *relPath = [NSString stringWithCString:cPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const  NSString *path = fullPathFromRelativePath(relPath);
    const char *c_path = [path UTF8String];
    return c_path;
}

static const char * relativeCPathForFile(const char *fileName)
{        
    NSString *relPath = [NSString stringWithCString:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];        
    const NSString *path = fullPathFromRelativePath(relPath);
    const char *c_path = [[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] UTF8String];    
    return c_path;
}
```

I'm getting quite a few messages like this in the debug console:

```
objc[4501]: Object 0x6e17060 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
objc[4501]: Object 0x6e12470 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
objc[4501]: Object 0x6e12580 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

What's the problem with the code ? ( I'm even using iOS 5 with "automated" retain/release, etc )

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This message shows up when you autorelease an object on a thread that does not have any release pools in its stack. By default, there is always an autorelease pool on the main thread. It's created and managed within the `UIApplicationMain()` function that is usually called by your app's main() function. However, additional threads you create (with `performSelectorInBackground:` or `NSThread`) do not have an autorelease pool in place unless you specifically put one there, so any autoreleased objects on that background thread have no pool to release them later, and will just leak.

If you're kicking something off to a background thread, the first thing you should do is create an autorelease pool. Under ARC, use the new `@autoreleasepool` construct to do that.

Comment: Hey there, this answer is correct. I was not creating more threads through any cocoa API's but I had some new threads being created by lower level C functions, which where the cause of this problem. I wrapped the first method around an @autoreleasepool and the problem got fixed.

Still wrapping my head around ARC :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the same code in a non-ARC application? You can confirm if it's an ARC problem or a real bug in the framework by doing that. ARC is still immature, Apple has stated many times that it isn't done yet and definitely has bugs.

If you are concerned about the number of apparent autorelease objects being created, use the `@autoreleasepool {...}` construct around the code in question. It's considerably [more efficient](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ARCProgrammingGuide/Introduction.html) than an NSAutoreleasePool, which you can't create in ARC code anyway.

Comment: Thanks!, still getting used to ARC :). Wrapping the code in the first method around @autoreleasepool fixed the issue. ( It's @autoreleasepool, not @autorelease )

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats a real leak. Apple has discussed this a few times, on the simulator it's a known pseudo-bug in how the simulator libraries deal with NSAutoReleasePool, but not significant enough to warrant fixing as your mac has considerably more memory than the device. At WWDC they mentioned that there are a few places where NSZombie doesn't deal with autorelease correctly, but I can't remember what session that was in. Unless you're noticing Leaks for those objects in Instruments, you shouldn't worry about it. If you do notice Leaks using instruments, file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Do not create an Autorelease Pool around your method just because it looks like it might be leaking. On ARC that just won't work anyway, and unless you've modified your main() function of your app, you have an autorelease pool wrapping **everything**. Creating an extra autorelease pool without profiling data indicating you have serious memory pressure after that method is called will actually make your application perform worse.

Comment: You don't have an autorelease pool wrapping everything if you've got code on the background thread; the autorelease pools UIKit creates for you only apply to the main thread.

Comment: That is true, and is probably one of the primary reasons Apple pushes devs to use block & GCD. But the OP didn't mention working on a background thread...

Comment: No, the OP didn't mention background threads, but this error happens almost exclusively on background threads unless you've modified your main() to not call UIApplicationMain(), which is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have removed NSAutoreleasePool calls in main.m file or if this code is being executed in a separated thread.
Because you can't use NSAutoreleasePool with ARC you have to put thread code in a @autoreleasepool block

Comment: NSAutoreleasePool [cannot be used in an ARC project](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ARCProgrammingGuide/Introduction.html), which the OP clearly stated this was. It won't compile.

Comment: Cannot use NSAutoreleasePool objects.
ARC provides @autoreleasepool blocks instead. These have an advantage of being more efficient than NSAutoreleasePool.

Comment: Copied from the page you gave me

Comment: That is correct. The recommendation you gave the poster will not work.