# Adding subviews with a loop in UIScrollView generates memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm trying to make a Springboard like application. So I got an UIScrollView in which I make a loop to generate a bunch of subviews from another UIViewController.

Here's my code :

```
@implementation ProjectsListViewController {
    ProjectViewController *icon;
}
```

-

```
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int page = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    icon = [[ProjectViewController alloc] init];

    icon.iconPath = @"icon.png";
    icon.iconTag = i;

    int x = (1024 * page) + ((50 + (10 * column)) +  (188 * column));
    int y = (40 + (150 * row));

    icon.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, icon.view.frame.size.width, icon.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.scrollView addSubview:icon.view];

    // Add a new page if we reach the end of one
    if ((column == 4) && (row == 3)) {
        row = 0;
        column = 0;
        page++;

        // Add a new line if we reached last column
    } else if (column == 4) {
        column = 0;
        row++;

        // Add a column otherwise
    } else {
        column++;
    }
}
```

All of this stuff goes in the viewDidLoad method. Until there if I run the app everything's fine, icons are there.
But when I want to click on an icon (there's a IBAction on a button to push to another view) my app crash because of possible memory leaks. It seems that there's no reference to the subviews anymore.

Only solution I found is to add each ProjectViewController inside a NSMutableArray. This way, I can click on icons and push another view.

Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Sorry if it sounds noob to your ears, I'm trying to learn !

Note: I'm using ARC.

Comment: Is the IBAction linked to the ProjectViewController?  If so, I think that is the issue. Also, does your "only solution I found" work or was that your only idea so far?

Comment: You need to provide a stack trace. Memory leak is not a source of crash (typically)

Comment: I'm missing the `addTarget` for each icon. Where do you set that?

Comment: @Maudicus Yes It is, I had in mind to have a little view for each icons. The solution I found works, yes, but as I'm quite new to Objective-C I don't know if it's a common pratice or a really ugly thing.

Comment: @ott The button is made in Interface Builder and linked to an IBAction  in the ProjectViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antoine the solution you made with the array works, I'd keep it like that.

To give insight to what is going wrong without the array
• icon is ProjectViewController (this is being created on the fly and being release by ARC)
• adding icon.view to any view will cause it to be retained by said view
• when the icon's action is triggered, it is attempting to message an instance of ProjectViewController that is no longer valid

Using your array (I am assuming it is a property (strong)), each instance of ProjectViewController added to the array will not be released by ARC and when your icon's action is triggered, the method is sent to a valid object.

Answer (score 1):

if nothing is referencing the icon class outside of the loop it will be collected by ARC. that's why adding them to a list solves the problem. you are adding the icon's view to a list so they end up referenced. but nothing keeps track of the icons themselves.

Comment: The icon objects goes out of scope at the end of the loop.  You need to manage icon objects in an array or dictionary so they are not released.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIButton's instead of images if they are being tied to to and IBAction.  That way you are keeping your code modular and you don't have to worry about managing the memory of two different objects and actions.

Also, You should check out the last answer to this question:
[Why does static NSString leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475727/why-does-static-nsstring-leak)

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
icon = [[ProjectViewController alloc] init];
```

I would do:

```
ProjectViewController *projectViewController = [[ProjectViewController alloc] init];
```

This way you create a new instance of ProjectViewController for every time through the loop, the other way reallocates the same UIViewController each time through.

Comment: if they are using ARC there is no need to call release.

Comment: Whoops, I did not see that. Sorry, I updated the code accordingly. Thanks